# How to resize an image in sharp with the option 'contain' but preserve the aspect ratio of the original dimensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

I have a 1000px by 750px image.

I use lovell/sharp to resize it:

```
await sharp(image)
    .resize({
        fit: sharp.fit.contain,
        width: 800,
        height: 800
    })
    .jpeg({ quality: 80 })
    .toBuffer()
```

This results in a new image that is 800px by 800px, with the original image 'contained' inside of that region.

What I would really like is to have a final image that is 800px by 600px.  IOW, to resize the image and preserve the aspect ratio.

I realize it is possible to do this by specifying only a width.  However it is useful to have a bounding box to contain the resized image in, to avoid creating images greater than a certain height.

Can I do this in sharp with different settings?

Comment: ermagherd, shoulda just checked the docs first: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/blob/master/docs/api-resize.md
sharp.fit.inside

Comment: indeed. Time to delete this question again.

Answer (score 23):

What I think you are willing to achieve:

```
await sharp(image)
    .resize(800, 800, {
        fit: 'inside',
    })
    .jpeg({ quality: 80 })
    .toBuffer()
```

Comment: This is precisely what we are trying to achieve. Should be accepted answer. (didn't need the quality setting not sure it's relevant)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @Methodician the quality setting comes from the OP code; when answering questions, it's most likely and recomended to use and refactor the code that the OP contains.

Answer (score 19):

Keep either `width` or `height` so that the Sharp will maintain the ratio

Below the height will be automatically maintained its ratio when resizing as we giving only the width value of the new image;

```
await sharp(image)
    .resize({
        fit: sharp.fit.contain,
        width: 800
    })
    .jpeg({ quality: 80 })
    .toBuffer()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a string to the fit property.

```
    let resizedPhoto
    await sharp(photoBuffer)
      .resize({ width: 1200, height: 900, fit: 'fill' })
      .toBuffer()
      .then((data) => {
        resizedPhoto = data
      })
      .catch((err) => {})
```